# How do I make these buttons inline? HTML ActionLink or Html.BeginForm issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm trying to make these buttons display next to each other, I'm guessing I would want it to be an inline-block style so there is some space between them. I have tried to add `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` (not at the same time) to `#being-survey-btn`, but no luck there. I've also attempted to add those properties to `.btn` but no luck there either. I've tried putting `<span>` tags around all of it (inside the divs) as well as putting `<span>` tags around the `<button>` tags and I've come up with nothing. Using bootstrap.

My cshtml:

```
<div id="finish-survey-container">
  <div id="finish-survey-items">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MakePDF", "HabitatManagement"))
    {
        <button id="begin-survey-btn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Save as PDF</button>
    }
    @if (ViewBag.Type == "Habitat Management")
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "HabitatManagement", new { userId = ViewBag.UserID }))
        {
            <button id="begin-survey-btn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Finish</button>
        }
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also attempted styling through an ActionLink (this is actually how I originally had it before trying out Html.BeginForm syntax):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save as PDF", "MakePDF", null, new { @id="begin-survey-btn", @class = "btn btn-default btn-lg", @style = "display: inline-block"})
```

I know I must be missing something rather obvious. Anybody have an idea?

**EDIT**

Generated HTML:

```
<div id="finish-survey-container">
  <div id="finish-survey-items">
    <form action="/HabitatManagement/MakePDF" method="post">
       <button id="begin-survey-btn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Save as PDF</button>
    </form>
    <form action="HabitatManagement?userId=#" method="post">
       <button id="begin-survey-btn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Finish</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you also post the generated HTML sometimes it's easier to reason about the generated html to see the issue.

Comment: Each button is inside a different form so you need to make those not be `block`. Something like `#finish-survey-items form{display:inline-block;}`

Comment: Given your HTML I'm guessing you're using Bootstrap. Your buttons _should_ be inline unless you have conflicting CSS / generated HTML that we can't see in the example. Could you please share the generated code?

Comment: @Andrei added generated html

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli That worked great. Thanks for an easy solution.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli was correct and it's what I assumed, the buttons are being wrapped around by a form where its CSS is pushing the buttons apart. try playing around with the `<form>` elements css to get it inline the buttons should not be moving themselves onto separate lines alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `Html.BeginForm` creates a `form` element, so your code will end up like 
this

```
<form>
  <button>..</button>
</form>
<form>
  <button>..</button>
</form>
```

Your problem is that the `form` elements are by default `block`. That is what you need to fix, and to do that you should set these `form` elements to be `display:inline-block`

Something like

```
#finish-survey-items form{display:inline-block;}
```